# accomplish ... with

Tags: phrase-meaning

[image]

> "You've accomplished a lot with this city"

I think it means "you have got a lot from the city - accomplished a better yourself."

The translated subtitles says "The city has become better because of your struggle".

What is the correct meaning?

Comment: The subtitles, literally, say, *You've accomplished a lot with this city.* Neither of your translations mean the same thing as that sentence. The sentence doesn't mean you've improved the city or yourself, nor does it mention anything about your struggle. It simply means that **whatever it is** that you've accomplished (it could be cooking good food), it's been because of (or alongside) the city. To know *a good* translation, we'd need to know what was said in the original language.

Comment: @JasonBassford, Katy said "To 'accomplish a lot with [something]' often means that you have succeeded in improving that thing.". Is it right?

Comment: No. It *might* mean that, but going from *accomplished* to *improved* is a bit of a leap. I could say that I've accomplished a lot with my life and mean that I've helped other people. Or that I've visited lots of places. Or that I've made lots of money. It doesn't mean I've improved my life—although I might have. *You've accomplished a lot with that needle and thread.* It doesn't mean you've improved the needle and thread—but done a lot with it. Most likely to sew clothes or suture patients. The sentence *itself* could be talking about a lot of different things. More context is needed.

Answer (score 1):

To "accomplish a lot **with** [something]" often means that you have succeeded in improving that thing.

For example, **She accomplished a lot with her students** means she helped them learn a lot. (Though "she accomplished a lot with her coworkers" would probably mean that they all were successful at their tasks together. There's a slight difference in meaning when the thing after "with" is subordinate to or in the care of the subject of the sentence as opposed to an equal.)

**You've accomplished a lot with this city** means something like "You've succeeded in making this city better," which is in line with the translation the subtitles give.